# Flutter/Dart copyCrop Function Exception: Could not instantiate image codec

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a cropped Image in Flutter. I use the Image.memory Widget. When I use the orginal image there is no Problem.

```
var tempStore = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);



    List<int> byteListe = await tempStore.readAsBytes();


    image = dartimage.Image.fromBytes(400, 400, byteList);
```

But after I used the copyCrop() Function I get an Exception.. 
https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/copyCrop.html

```
cropImage = dartimage.copyCrop(image, 4, 0, 100, 100); 

     Expanded(
                child: Container(

                  child: cropImage != null ? Image.memory(cropImage.getBytes()): Text('No Image'),
                ),
              ),
```

This is the Exception!

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown while resolving an image:
Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:4304:5)
#1      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:1682:10)
#2      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodec (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:88:12)
#3      MemoryImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:714:18)
#4      MemoryImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:706:14)
...
Image provider: MemoryImage(_Uint8ArrayView#a573e, scale: 1.0)
Image configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#c13af(), devicePixelRatio: 4.0, locale: de_DE, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
Image key: MemoryImage(_Uint8ArrayView#a573e, scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```